# Why am I getting a bunch of empty cells when using concat for two dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a .xlsx file I am creating two dataframes from and then trying to concat them so that the right columns append to the bottom of the left columns. How do I get the data in the 2nd dataframe to move directly below the 1st dataframe?

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx')
header = data[['col_1', 'col_2', 'col_3']]
detail = data[['col_4', 'col_5', 'col_6']]
combined = pd.concat([header, detail], ignore_index=True)
combined.to_csv('output.csv', header=None)
```

**test.xlsx**

| col_1 | col_2 | col_3 | col_4 | col_5 | col_6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aaaaa | bbbbb | ccccc | ddddd | eeeee | fffff |

**Actual: output.csv**

| col_1 | col_2 | col_3 | col_4 | col_5 | col_6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aaaaa | bbbbb | ccccc |  |  |  |
|  |  |  | ddddd | eeeee | fffff |

**Expected: output.csv**

| col_1 | col_2 | col_3 | col_4 | col_5 | col_6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aaaaa | bbbbb | ccccc |  |  |  |
| ddddd | eeeee | fffff |  |  |  |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply change the column names then combine:

```
header = data[['col_1', 'col_2', 'col_3']]
detail = data[['col_4', 'col_5', 'col_6']]
detail.columns = ['col_1', 'col_2', 'col_3']
# or use detail.columns = header.columns

combined = pd.concat([header, detail], axis = 0)
```

Comment: This also works when the columns are the same count between the two dataframes but gives the error "Length mismatch: Expected axis has 29 elements, new values have 25 elements" when they are not the same count.

Comment: Answers given suit the data you gave in the question. I suggest you ask a new question with sample data which exemplifies the new case and the expected output specifically on how the 'excess' columns are to be handled.

Comment: On reflection combining disparate numbers of columns can usually be handled by using reindex so that the missing elements will be replaced by `NaN`. But because there are numerous possible arrangements (which columns have the missing elements?) you need to specify in detail a typical arrangement showing what you want.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
cols = ['col_1', 'col_2', 'col_3']
header = data[cols]
detail = data[['col_4', 'col_5', 'col_6']].set_axis(cols, axis=1)
combined = pd.concat([header, detail], ignore_index=True).reindex(data.columns, axis=1)
```

Comment: This worked with my simplified example, however, in testing with the full file I am having an issue that I believe is caused because the two dataframes don't have the same number of columns. The error is "Length mismatch: Expected axis has 29 elements, new values have 25 elements".